# Manipulando td's de tabelas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um código que reparte em três tabelas as informações que chegam do banco de dados. Porém quando eu filtro esses resultados por nome e código(campos disponiveis na DOM para filtrar as tabelas) as linhas () da tabela ficam bagunçadas porque o que eu faço é esconder as linhas que nao atendem o filtro. Existe um jeito de reinserir na tabela as linhas que eu quero e apagar as que existiam antes? 
Se ajudar, as  sao exemplo:

```
<td nome=x codigo=y>Dado</td>
```

Os campos de pesquisao sao exemplo:

```
<input type='text' id='pesquisa_nome'>
<input type='number' id='pesquisa_codigo'>
```

Comment: Voce nao pode usar um plugin de tabelas pra fazer isso ? ja que esta usando jQuery

Comment: Não sei, vc sabe de algum pra eu pesquisar sobre?

Comment: Vou fazer um resposta com que funciona bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como voce esta utilizando jQuery, acredito que a maneira mais simples de ter esse resultado seria utilizando um plugin na manipulacao de tabelas, no exemplo abaixo, estou utilizando o [DataTables](https://datatables.net):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

**Como funciona:**

Basta criar a tabela normalmente, porem e importante ter o `<thead>` e `<tbody>` marcados, e instanciar o elemento `(#example)` da tabela a chamada do plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Referencia do exemplo: [Zero Configuration](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

Comment: Cara, na verdade é simples o que eu quero fazer, só guardo os elementos TR da tabela em um array e mostro eles, dividindo em três tabelas. se eu só dar .hide() nos que eu nao quero mostrar a tabela fica torta, por isso eu tenho que retirar todos, filtrar os que eu quero adicionar e depois inserir esse array de tds que eu quero mostrar

Comment: O array eu estou conseguindo fazer, agora só preciso tirar todos os elementos tr da tabela e inserir os que passaram no filtro

Comment: @MateusAlberghini coloca um exemplo mesmo que sem funcionar na pergunta, acho que entendi errado sua duvida

Comment: Eu acabei conseguindo cara, mas obrigado por tentar ajudar ;)